# how to change local functions of highcharts

Tags: javascript, plugins, highcharts, closures

Highcharts.numberFormat is a pointer to a local function in the Highcharts closure. Highcharts uses the local function internally. how someone can change this (or any other local function inside closure such as dateFormat, etc.) outside of original source as a plugin or something?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your question is to change the internal function's behavior within the closure.

As far as I've understand the src of the highcharts, there is no way to change the internal functions defined inside the closure, unless you edit the source file (*I'd not recommend this at all*).

The principal behind this is, the library itself uses those functions for internal purposes, therefore change in such functions will lead to undesired behavior of the library.

Hopefully, I'm making sense.

Comment: you mean there is no way other than modifying the source itself, right?

Comment: @pajooh yes, there is no way if you want to change the internal behavior of those functions outside the closure. The library actually doesn't use the namespaced functions, it only exports to namespace at the end of the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wrap() function in this way:

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts

Comment: numberFormat and dateFormat are local functions,
wrap works for prototypes.

can you provide a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can overwrite the numberFormat : http://jsfiddle.net/4hdbY/2/

```
(function (Highcharts, UNDEFINED)
{   "use strict";

    if ( ! Highcharts )
    {
        return;
    }

    var numberFormat_orig = Highcharts.numberFormat;
    Highcharts.numberFormat = function ( value ) 
    {
        // the original number formatter
        // return numberFormat_orig.apply(this, arguments);

        // your custom code 
        return '~' + Math.round(value);
    };

}(Highcharts));
```

the solution is designed according to the Highcharts-excension rules.

I highly doubt, you should overwrite the default number formatter, instead, you could also call a custom function or even bind it to the Highcharts. This mighgt me done easily according to the shown code.
See the code where it used:

```
tooltip: {
  valueSuffix: '°C' , 
  formatter: function() {
    return '<b> Temperature: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y) + '°C</b><br/>'+ 'in Month: '+ this.x;
  }
}
```

this can be easily modified, to use your own function.

Comment: Actually this is not overriding the actual function, but gives an impression of function of highcharts because you are using it's namespace. This is just as `XYZ.numberFormat(val)`

Comment: How would you overwrite a 'function' in JS (where you have no access to the memory itself)? i really'd like to see an example.